# ASP.NET MVC submit empty string to WebApi Controller on jquery serialize()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to POST data from ASP.NET MVC View to WebApi Controller via j Query $.post(), but I'm always receiving just empty string (what's interesting - this work fine with Web Forms).
Here is JS.

```
$("#searchbtn").click(function () {
    var ser = $("div#hotels").serialize();
    $.post('/api/hotelsavailablerq', { '': ser });
});
```

Here is how ApiController signature look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostHotelsAvailableRq([FromBody] string q)
```

View using just pure HTML forms - div, select, input type=text. Nothing Binded from model.

Comment: try this: $.post('api/hotelsavailablerq', "=" + ser);

Comment: No, this is not working as well, unfortunately.

Comment: Guys, before post again about make sure that hotelsavailablerq should be method name. No! It's not. Please read this article about WebApi Controller routing http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: So that sounds like XY problem. The actual problem is not that ApiController receiving empty string, but $("div#hotels").serialize() returns an empty string in the client side?

Comment: is "hotelsavailablerq" controller name?if yes the above code should work properly and there must be problem with serialization.

Comment: Yes, hotelsavailablerq and yes, this is what I told many times - problem is on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found answer - RTFM.
When I read carefully `jQuery` documentation about `serizlization`, I found that:
1. `<form>` tag should exist.
2. Each control should have `name` attribute.
All these things has by default in web form, but in MVC I should add its manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $.post('/api/hotelsavailablerq', { 'q': ser });
```

`string q` should be of the same type which you are sending from the jQuery.

Comment: No, there is something else.

Comment: Actually, the problem not about Controller, problem is in View or jQuery, as variable ser get empty string.

Comment: Yes, when you make request to WebApi and sending primitive objects you should not provide object parameters' name.

Comment: I mean that from Firebug I can see that javascript varibale that must contain url formatted string is empty BEFORE it's sent to Controller. So definitely it's not about Controller.

Answer (score 0):

try another:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/hotelsavailablerq',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
    data: JSON.stringify(ser)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code to hit the controller. Make sure there is **hotelsavailablerq** action method in **api** controller.

```
$("#searchbtn").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: '/api/hotelsavailablerq',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('div#hotels').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
});});
```

Comment: hotelsavailablerq is controller class name and it's used in controller as controller route name, but NOT METHOD NAME!